# Display randomly picked words in a string - Python

Tags: python

I have a for loop with random.choice item.

I have to add all same items into a string after exiting for loop.

How do I do this?

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango', 'orange']
unit = ['tbsp', 'tsp', 'cup', 'mls']

for x in range(2):
    fruits_choice = random.choice(fruits)
    unit_choice = random.choice(unit)
    measure = random.randint(1, 5)
    print(measure, unit_choise, fruit_choice)

print("Mix the", ..?..)
```

In place of ? there should be the same list of fruits randomly picked before.

Comment: Hello and welcome! What is the output you're trying to obtain?

Comment: The list listing all the items first and then the string telling to mix all those items together.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show an explicit example of the output you might expect? It's ambiguous what order you're expecting and whether or not you want the measures in the output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be explicit about it, you can of course store the choices in a new list:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango', 'orange']
unit = ['tbsp', 'tsp', 'cup', 'mls']
picked = []

for x in range(2):
    fruits_choice = random.choice(fruits)
    unit_choice = random.choice(unit)
    measure = random.randint(1, 5)
    picked.append((measure, unit_choice, fruit_choice))

for p in picked:
    print("Mix the %u %s %s" % p)
```